# Find the derivative of $F(x) = \int_{a}^b \frac{x}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the derivative of $$F(x) = \int_{a}^b \dfrac{x}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt.$$

**Attempt:**

We use the product rule since $\displaystyle \int_{a}^b \dfrac{x}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt = x  \int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt$ to get that $$F'(x) = \int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt.$$

Comment: Your attempt looks fine to me.

Comment: yup that looks okay

Comment: I think you are also expected to perform integration

Comment: @ArchisWelankar You cannot perform that integration from a random $a$ to $b$

Comment: Hmm you are right

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are absolutely correct. 
Given $$F(x) = \int_{a}^b \dfrac{x}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt$$
Here $x$ is a variable and $$\int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt$$ is a constant. Let it be $v$. So $$F(x)=vx$$ We know that derivative of $vx$ is $v$.
So, $$F'(x) =v= \int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt$$
The above integration is not possible as it isn't an integrable function. So,$$F'(x) =v= \int_{a}^b \dfrac{1}{1+t^2+\sin^2{t}}dt$$